# Where do these solder mask pot holes/marks come from?

Tags: pcb

When ordering from a manufacturer I can spot these markings on the solder mask, they are located sometimes around drill/vias. Anyone knows why they are there? And why not all manufacturers have them?

[image: solder mask marks pot holes]

I specifically get these when ordering from Eurocircuits. I dont see these marking when ordering from jlcpcb (from China) for example.
I could expect such anomalies/markings to exist when ordering from cheap chineese manufacturers, but since I get them only from my expensive manufacturer, I had to ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Scott suggested I emailed the manufacturer. They say:

> The marks found on the card are incidental during the vacuum
> utilization of the Ledia direct image machine and are purely aesthetic
> in nature, without any impact on its operation.

And giving me this [link](https://www.eurocircuits.com/blog/eurocircuits-install-ledia-v5-direct-imaging-di/) which reads:

> ... we made one of our largest investments in a single piece of
> machinery when we installed a Ledia V5 direct imaging system from
> Japanese image-processing company Screen....
>
> The Ledia V5 allows us to offer finer dams than are possible with
> conventional imaging technology.

So they use a technique that is more accurate, it just leaves these marks behind.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a quality control issue to me.  If it happens repeatedly, I'd stop using this vendor, as board makers are a dime a dozen.  A bubble in the mask isn't necessarily important, but it suggests their quality systems are not up to snuff.  This is just the problem you see.  There may be others you can't.

Another option would be to send the photos to their customer support, and ask them to redo it correctly.  I wouldn't bother if it were a small batch.